Initially I'm loading some videos from server, it working correctly. But I'm loading more videos form server its not initializing
I'm trying to make an app like instagram, Initially loading certain video will work correctly but when loading more videos from server player not initializing, Please help with related issue,
What to do to initialize the loaded videos form the server,

provide your code. we cant guess what you written.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
